# What does an interchange do?

Tags: mini-metro

After a couple weeks, I got an upgrade option that says "Upgrade one station to an interchange". What does an interchange do and when should I upgrade a station to one?

Comment: I think it speeds up loading and unloading.

Comment: it'd be nice if they made this clearer in-game

Answer (score 24, accepted):

From the [patch notes](http://devlog.dinopoloclub.com/post/83350676170/mini-metro-alpha9) (emphasis mine):

> The possible upgrades are railcar (same as before), railcar speed upgrade (all railcars increase in speed), platform upgrade (all stations increase in capacity), **interchange (upgrade one station to hold 18 passengers, and load / unload at 4x speed)**, extra tunnels (two extra tunnels).